# pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (six 1.3.0), Requirement.parse('six>=1.5'))

Tags: openshift, pyramid

I went to build a new python pyramid app on OpenshiftV2 like I always do today and I get this error when I deployed to openshift.  I ssh'd in and I can see my virtual env has six 1.10.0 install but for some reason openshift thinks I have 1.3.  Maybe Openshift is not activating the venv?  Openshift will not let me pip upgrade, install, or uninstall.

I seem to remember this happening a couple of years ago but can't remember how to resolve.  I seem to remember it was a Openshift bug but not sure.

Any ideas?

```
  File "/opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 728, in require
needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
File "/opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 630, in resolve
raise VersionConflict(dist,req) # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (six 1.3.0     (/opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages), Requirement.parse('six>=1.5'))
```

Answer (score 1):

The Openshift repo must have been corrupted somehow.  I deleted the app and recreated from scratch and it works fine now.

Comment: I'm hitting this too, but have yet to find a resolution. Mine is pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (six 1.5.2 (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('six>=1.10.0'))

Comment: @sager89  I believe my issue was that I force pushed my local project first  to Openshift before I merged with it.  I was experimenting with different remote repos yesterday.  The Openshift repo has has special hooks that activate the virtual environment and if those get wiped out it never gets activated hence the old version of "six" is used.